# How to disable case sensitive path segments for API Gateway RestAPI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-rest-api

Recently, I noticed that requests to RestAPIs in API Gateway are path case-sensitive.

How exactly can I disable this so that it is no longer case sensitive?
Is this even possible?

Id like my request to api.company.com/**p**rod to work along with api.company.com/**P**rod

Can an expert AWS API Gateway expert chime in here? Is this really a hard constraint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the AWS API Gateway request path case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53225519/how-to-make-the-aws-api-gateway-request-path-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

AWS is case sensitive by design, but here's a good answer may help to accomplish what you're looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53228443/10348028

That guy explains some good options you may use

Comment: How do I trace requests that come into the RestAPI and dont map to a stage based on case sensitivity?